# Как установить phpmyadmin на Windows?

Tags: windows, phpmyadmin, windows-7, openserver, установка

Скачал openserver 5.4.3 и обнаружил, что внутри этой версии нет phpmyadmin. Скачал архив с https://php-myadmin.ru/download/ phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-all-lagnuages.zip. Как установить phpmyadmin?

Comment: Судя по их же [докам](https://ospanel.io/docs/#rabota-s-mysql), он там должен быть. phpMyAdmin -- написан на PHP, там не будет иснталяшки. Про уставновку можете почитать в [документации](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html)

Comment: @Simon мне нужно phpmyadmin установить на windows.

Comment: на мой взгляд phpmyadmin - что-то древнее и не нужное. Мне кажется есть ПО и с UI получше и поудобнее в использовании. Ну типа всякие Navicat или Dbeaver и подобные

Comment: @vladwebsearch это очевидно, если Вы используете OpenServer, который работает только на Windows.

Comment: @vladwebsearch судя по скриншотам и описанию на сайте ospanel, там есть phpMyAdmin в указанной версии. `Доп. софт: Adminer 4.7.8 / PHPMemcachedAdmin 1.3 / PHPMyAdmin 5.0.4 / PHPPgAdmin 7.12.1 / PHPRedisAdmin 1.13.1`